# PhalconPHP install undefined symbol: compiler_globals

Tags: php, phalcon, zts

I installed php 7.2.2 with ZTS enabled.

PHP 7.2.2 (cli) (built: Jul 20 2018 17:47:46) ( ZTS DEBUG )
Copyright (c) 1997-2018 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.2.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2018 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.2.2, Copyright (c) 1999-2018, by Zend Technologies

I've also successfully installed phalcon, find / -type f -name 'phalcon.so' returns

/usr/lib/php/20170718/phalcon.so
/etc/php/7.2-zts/lib/php/extensions/debug-zts-20170718/phalcon.so

When I do php -v I get:

HP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'phalcon.so' (tried: /etc/php/7.2-zts/lib/php/extensions/debug-zts-20170718/phalcon.so (/etc/php/7.2-zts/lib/php/extensions/debug-zts-20170718/phalcon.so: undefined symbol: compiler_globals)

How can I solve this?

Comment: Seen similar with load order. Where is phalcon extension included? Suggest `20-phalcon.ini` in conf.d. Well that and possibly confusion about `which php`...

Comment: There is no conf.d file available on the entire system. I'm running in cli mode by the way :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I did in the end is compiling Phalcon with the compiler instead of using apt.

This allows Phalcon to detect my version and collect the right one.

Comment: I had a similar error when I tried to use the TS version of Phalcon, while PHP was NTS. The problem has solved by using the NTS version of Phalcon.